# Restoring a Windows XP NTBackup file (.bkf) file on Windows 8

Tags: windows-xp, windows-8, windows-backup

Is there a way to read a BKF file from Windows XP using Windows 8? I tried installing the Windows 7 restore only pkg from the Microsoft web page (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974674), but the update failed on my Windows 8 system with a certificate error message.

FWIW, I can still read my Sun backup tapes from 20 years ago. This XP file is 5 years old...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download and extract [nt5backup.cab](http://www.stsanford.com/pebuilder) or [xp_files.rar](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/26490-63-open-file#t113739), run **NTBackup.exe**, ignore errors about the Removable Storage service not running, open your BKF and restore your files:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

<sub>[Source](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/restore-bkf-file-ntbackup-windows-7-vista/)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. Links worked, but now I have a different problem. My backupfile is about 100G & restore failed when loading "backup file contains unrecognized data and cannot be used". This file was saved to tape via gtar (which had no trouble restoring it) & passed the MD5 checksum. Failed reading from NAS, so I copied to local drive & same error.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, never used Windows' built-in backup, ever (never trusted it to get things right).

Comment: Also remember to run ntbackup.exe as an administrator. Otherwise, depending on permissions of the original files and the destination directory, many of your files will fail to be restored.  I learned this the hard way.

Comment: +1 This worked great! I successfully restored individual files from a .BKF generated on XP. I was beginning to worry I'd have to setup up a Vista (or lower) VM just to recover data from our XP archives. (I can also confirm that the files passed a virus scan, for those who might have such concerns.)

Answer (score 2):

After less than successful attempts at having NTRestore read my old backup file, I found a project [mtftar](http://freecode.com/projects/mtftar) which transcodes a NTbackup file (bkf) into a standard tar file. Recovered 100K files no problem with tar.